# PHP echo json_encode does not display but reads

Tags: php, json

so I have this code:

```
  <?php
$json = array(
    'name' => 'Test'
);

echo json_encode($json);
```

and when I ran it on screen i just got a blank screen with no data shown.
However I decided to run the php file through my servers command line and this happened:

```
root@vps:/var/www/iN# php test.php
{"name":"Test"}
root@vps:/var/www/iN#
```

As you can see it outputs the JSON there but not to my browser, is there something i'm missing or have to do?

EDIT:
my apache2 needed a restarting apache seems to have fixed it even tho I tried that twice, I don't really know why that happened, thanks tho :)

Comment: "on screen"? You mean via your browser? or via the gnu "screen" terminal multiplexer app? if it's via browser, then turn on display_errors/error_reporting: white page on a php script means something blew up and all error display options are disabled.

Comment: @MarcB yes, "on screen" being my chrome browser and I have fixed it. My apache 2 needed a restart for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code.

```
<?php
$json = array(
    'name' => 'Test'
);

echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Gives at my system the expected output:

```
{"name":"Test"}
```

Either check your code again for a missing character, or check your server?

Comment: Yea it was my apache on my server, sorry :)

Comment: No problem.
Glad you got it fixed.

Comment: just in case, you can try with php built in server as "php -S localhost:portnumber"